# Count Checked Check with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for some advice, so I have some checkboxes. I would like to Add a dynamic count so that it shows the number that was selected.

So far I have

```
$('.individual').length
```

Which returns the number but how would I add it to my span:

```
<li><p class="records-selected"><span id="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span> of 29 records selected</p></li>
<li><a href="#" class="number-records">Select All 29 Records</a></li>
```

This is what is on my Table Data

```
<td><label><input type="checkbox" class="individual" /></label></td>
```

I forgot to mention that on my application, the table is loaded with Ajax, would I just need to add it to my AJAX callback?

Comment: `$('#count-checked-checkboxes').text($('.individual').length)`

Comment: `$('#count-checked-checkboxes').text($('.individual:checked').length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. I used **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** of jQuery to add text.

```js
$(".1").on("change", check);

function check(){
  if($(".1:checked").length>0){
    $('p').show();   //instead of $('p') select whatever you want show(selector for that text)
    $("#selected").text($(".1:checked").length);
    $("#total").text($(".1").length);
  }
  else{
    $('p').hide();  //instead of $('p') select whatever you want hide(selector for that text)
  }
}
check();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="1">1
<input type="checkbox" class="1">2
<input type="checkbox" class="1">3
<input type="checkbox" class="1">4
<input type="checkbox" class="1">5

<p><span id="selected"></span> of <span id="total"></span> checkbox selected</p>
```

Comment: Is it possible to hide the text, then show it once a checkbox is selected?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I also have a select all button with the class .select all is there a way to also show that that also?

Comment: could you do an example using a select all option please, so that if you select all it counts them?

Comment: @Rob I can't do it in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery .text() and pass the length to it like so:

```
$('#count-checked-checkboxes').text($('.individual').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('#count-checked-checkboxes').text($('.individual:checked').length)
```